# Laravel mail attachment issue

Tags: php, laravel

I haven't used Laravel's mail class before and i'm having a little trouble attaching files via a contact form. This is what I have:

```
public function mailer(){

    $fromEmail = Input::get('email');
    $fromName = Input::get('name');
    $phone = Input::get('phone');
    $subject = 'New Enquiry';
    $contactMessage = Input::get('message');
    $path = Input::get('files');

    $data = array('name'=>$fromName, 'email'=>$fromEmail, 'comment'=>$contactMessage, 'phone' => $phone);

    Mail::send('contactemail', $data, function($message) use ($fromEmail, $fromName, $subject, $path)
    {
        $message->to('stack-example@gmail.com', 'Enquiries');

        $message->from($fromEmail, $fromName);

        $message->subject($subject);
        $message->attach($path);
    });
}
```

It's throwing me the error:

> fopen(stack-example-file.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Mailer functions as it should without attachment. Any ideas as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I had

```
Input::get('files');
```

instead of

```
Input::file('files');
```

Which resulted in a string rather than a file object. I had also moved from blade templating to vanilla html for the form tag and forgot to add

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

to replace

```
'files' => true
```

File object was null as a result and therefore not attachable.